# How to request more than 5k records from a contract

Tags: contract-deployment, statistics

Trying to request all the records from a contract. The etherscan.io solution offers a 5k records but the total is 120k+. Any API endoint or solution can go through it all?

What I tried:

- ethslurp, limited to 10k (Dont remember the exact number).
- Etherscan.io (didn't find an API that provide as [in](https://etherscan.io/exportData?type=address&a=0x80e9540c204c05be63cfe44b43302780175b60ff)

> Would like a .csv if possible

Comment: Instead of relying on third party services, you can install your own node and scan through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try Zapper.

Here's a link:
https://api.zapper.fi/api/static/index.html#/Historical%20Transactions/TransactionController_getTransactions

Comment: getting this here
`
{
  "statusCode": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized"
}
`

Comment: Go to top of page you will see this white and green button "Athorize". Click on that and then paste the key they give you on the pop up into the input field and click authorize again

Comment: Thank you so much. Here it returns a JSON without the whole historical data. Did I do it right? 

https://api.zapper.fi/v1/transactions?address=0x80e9540c204c05Be63cfE44b43302780175b60FF&network=ethereum&api_key=96e0cc51-a62e-42ca-acee-910ea7d2a241

Comment: Accepted. Tks! Actually, it seems kinda limited, in the etherscan they say the contract has 123k transactions.

Comment: I've heard it caps with timeout, so you can try awaiting it

Answer (score 1):

You can do more than a million request per hour by running your own node. It will cost you around 50 - 100 eur/month. [More information here](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Etherscan API](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-normal-transactions-by-address) that as a 10k limit and perform multiple API requests. (e.g. from 0 to 9999, 10 000 to 19 999, etc...).

I wrote a script that query all transactions for an address and export the result into a CSV file here : https://github.com/flbouchut/etherscan-exporter